# Rails 4.2.5 reassign value to serialized field after SerializationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a serialized column

```
class TestSerialize < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :parameters, Array
end
```

When I tried to assign String

```
a = TestSerialize.new
a.parameters = "inappropriate type"
```

as expected I got

```
ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch:Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String. -- "inappropriate type".
```

But when I tried to reassign "parameters" field, I still got the same error with the previous assigned value

```
a.parameters = []
ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String. -- "inappropriate type"
```

Is it expected behaviour?

```
2.2.3 :003 > a = TestSerialize.new
 => #<TestSerialize id: nil, parameters: [], first_name: {}, last_name: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.2.3 :004 > a.parameters
 => [] 
2.2.3 :005 > a.parameters = "test"
ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String. -- "test"

2.2.3 :006 > a
ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String. -- "test"

2.2.3 :007 > a.parameters
ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String. -- "test"

2.2.3 :008 > a.first_name
 => {} 

2.2.3 :009 > reload!
Reloading...
 => true 
2.2.3 :010 > a
ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String. -- "test"
```

Comment: Are you doing this in the console?

Comment: you mean rails console? Yes

Comment: Did you try reloading the console after the first error?

Comment: No I didn't, Also I have a test that throws this error after upgrading from 4.1.13 to 4.2.5

Comment: Ok. Try reloading the console and tell me.

Comment: I don't have a full explanation yet but it seems that the issue rises event before the reassignment, simply accessing the field after the invalid assignment raises the error again (`a.parameters = 3; a.parameters`).

Comment: When reload the console error still occur. After object reload error disappear!

Comment: @Dani even when you try to access object

Comment: @FriendlyFire, I didn't reload the console, so I can still access the object, but retrieving the serialized field throws the exception again, instead of producing `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from Rails team
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23449